# Issues while installing Git Server

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am working on to install a private Git Server at my place, so that I can manage my repo locally on LAN. 
I installed the `git-core` on my server and its running on `ubuntu`.

I don't have much knowledge about the SSH. So I want to know on which system I should create a SSH key pair, on the client or server?
And any further processes to make Git work in a client server model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate the SSH key (which includes both a public and private key) on the client, then upload the public half to the server (so it can validate your identity; by knowing the public part of the key, the server can validate your identity by decrypting something encrypted with the private half), and keep the private half **private**. (usually that means protecting it with a passphrase)

See more information [here, on the GitHub site](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). While that information is specific to GitHub, the process is going to be similar for any git server (or SSH, or any service utilizing SSH, for that matter). For instructions specific to Ubuntu, see [this question on the Ask Ubuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login).

Comment: Nice explanation @Mike how to upload the public key to the server it the server is  placed remotely?

Comment: That depends on the server; some (like GitHub) may have a web interface for the user to paste in her private key; if you are simply using a user account on an Ubuntu machine you will need to follow the instructions in the Ask Ubuntu question, or manually create the `.ssh` directory and `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and place the private key within the `authorized_keys` file. You should also make sure to `chmod 700 .ssh` and `chmod 700 .ssh/authorized_keys`; this ensures no other users can read or modify the sensitive contents of the `.ssh` directory. The `ssh-copy-id` program does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gitosis to manage the server. Instructions on setup including ssh keys is here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gitosis